# How do I use My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory with My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to use it like this:

```
Public Class Form1


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(
        "http://magicalexample.com/multi.zip", "My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory\multi.zip")
    Process.Start("cmd", "/k jar xf multi.zip")
    MsgBox("Done.")
End Sub
End Class
```

(note: I screwed up the formatting, it's right in VB, don't worry lol)

When I try to use the update button, it tells me that destinationFileName needs to include a file name. Do they not play well together or what?

Answer (score 1):

My.Computer.FileSystem.CourrentDirectory is a variable and isn't going to be magically parsed into your string. You need to concatenate the variable with the file location:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://magicalexample.com/multi.zip", My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\multi.zip")
```

Or use the [Path.Combine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to merge the directory plus filename:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://magicalexample.com/multi.zip", Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory, "multi.zip"))
```

Note that your examples aren't working for various reasons. They need the http:// in front of them AND the file must exist at the source (cannot be a 404 Not Found Error). Also, the extra semi colon in the comments you posted seems to indicate that it wouldn't even be compiling so you might be running a prior version. I created a new project and as an example ran this code which worked to download the google logo from the main page.

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png", Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory, "logo.png"))
```

Comment: I have tried both of these, and it still gives me "destinationFileName needs to include a file name."

Comment: Is that happening in DownloadfiLe or is that an error message displayed to the console window from the command prompt  in the Process.Start line? In other words, what gives you the message? An exception is being thrown or something is writing it to the screen? Show all that you can

Comment: After correcting your code with mine can you re-copy/paste your code exactly as it is? I'm interested to see something.

Comment: Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(
            "http://example.com/MultiTool/current/zip/multi.zip", Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory, "multi.zip"))
        Process.Start("cmd", "/k jar xf multi.zip")
        MsgBox("Done.")
    End Sub
End Class

Comment: Verified that it both Requires "http://" AND it must exist. The file in this case does NOT exist on the remote server. I run the code and get a 404 not found.

Comment: It has http:// in the actual code. I just quickly changed it because I don't really want the link to be public. The file does exist on the actual link.